# Rails 4 with jQuery - on select function in form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, select

I'm trying to figure out how to amend my form in my rails app.

The form currently has 2 questions.

the first question asks the user to choose an organisation. If the organisation they want is not listed, there is an option to choose other.

If they choose other, I want to show a second question.

In my form, I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@organisation_request) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>
            <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.input :organisation_id, collection: @all_organisations << ['other', nil] %>
                </div>

        <div id="organisation_request_name_content" class="content hidden">

          <div class="form-inputs">
            <%= f.input :name %>
          </div>
        </div>  

                <div class="form-actions">
                    <%= f.button :submit, "Create", :class => 'formsubmit' %>
                </div>
          <% end %>
```

In my app/assets/javascripts/organisation_requests.js, I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#organisation_request_organisation_id").on('select', function() {
      if (jQuery(this)[0] == 'other') {
          jQuery('#organisation_request_name_content').removeClass('hidden');
      } else {
          jQuery('#organisation_request_name_content').addClass('hidden');
      }
   });


});
```

When I save all of this and try it - the second question is hidden, but it does not reveal when I select other as an input to the first question.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: You are treating a dom element as an array. Hint: What does `jQuery(this)` refer to?  Use your console...

Comment: @RubyRacer - I'm afraid I don't understand any of that. I thought (this) meant this argument. I'm not at all sure what you're suggestion I use my rails console to do to progress my search for a solution

Comment: I mean use your development console, in the browser. `This`refers to an element. How do you expect this[0] to be string?

Comment: I'm not sure how to user it in the console to improve this code. Thank you - but I think your skills are too advanced for my level of comprehension.

Comment: to start with, you don't show what `#project_has_milestones` is. I guess it's a select input? You can write in your code `console.log(jQuery(this))` and check in you browser console. Providing more info can help others assist you more constructively.

Comment: @RubyRacer - project_has_milestones has been updated (it should be organisation_request_organisation_id). I want to check if the organisation_id is selected as 'other', if it is, then I want to reveal the 2nd question. Thank you. I'll try to figure out what your suggestion means.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check against the value of the select input.

The text in the selected option, for `other` would be `other`, while the value of the input will become the value assigned to `other`, in this case,  `NULL`

So,  you could use the following `if` statement instead:

```
if (jQuery(this).val() == NULL ) {
```

Also, instead of using `select` event, which applies to selecting text, you should use `change`, like this:

```
jQuery("#organisation_request_organisation_id").on('change', function() {
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I tried this, but it doesnt work. When I select "other" as the answer to the 1st question, the second question does not display.